# Problems when updating an MySQL database, python

Tags: python, mysql

In the example below there is two dataframes, df and df1. I also have a MySQL database with two tables. Tables1 and Table2, both has the same columns as df.

What I want to do is:

1. Use df1 to locate the correct row in table1,
2. Move the row to table2 and update the columns 'REMOVED' (From False to True) and 'REMOVED_DATE (from None to '2022-01-10).
3. Remove the row from table1

Below you see my effort. But it dosen't work, and I can imagine there is a better solution available. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[25, 10],
              'DATE':['2021-11-13', '2021-12-03'],
              'LOC': ['NY', 'ML'],
                'MAIL':['person1@gmail.com', 'person2@gmail.com'],
                 'NR': ['100000', '200000'],
                'REMOVED': [False, False],
                 'REMOVED_DATE':[None,None]})

df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[25],
                  'REMOVED':[True],
                 'REMOVED_DATE':['2022-01-11']})

cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()]) #use df to mirror the columns in the tables in the database.

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    id=row['ID']
    sql=f"SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE id={id}" # Check if ID is in table1.
    cursor.execute(sql)
    z=cursor.fetchall()
    
    if not z:
        print('insert') # if not, move on.
  
    else: #If ID in, update, move and delete
        sql=f"""UPDATE table1 SET (`" +cols + "`) VALUES (" + "%s,"*(len(row)-1) + "%s) WHERE id={id}""" # Update the whole row where ID match.
        cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        mydb.commit()
        sql=f"""INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id={id}""" #insert it into table2
        cursor.execute(str(sql), tuple(row))
        mydb.commit()
        sql=f"""DELETE from table1 WHERE id={id}""" # Delete it from table1
        cursor.execute(sql)
        mydb.commit()
```

Comment: You're missing parameters in the `cursor.execute()` for the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: WHy are you updating table1 if you're going to delete the row?

Comment: A better solution is, perhaps, to move it first to table2 and then update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update `table1` -- there's nothing in the specification that indicates this is needed, and you're going to delete it anyway.

Your code doesn't change `REMOVED` and `REMOVED_DATE` when it's copying from `table1` to `table2`. You can do this by replacing `SELECT *` with selecting all the columns other than those, and substituting the new values you want in the `SELECT` list.

You should also use parametrized queries rather than substituting values with f-strings.

```
cols = ",".join(f"`{col}`" for col in df.columns.tolist())
new_cols = ",".join('%s' if col in ('REMOVED', 'REMOVED_DATE') else f"`{col}`" for col in df.columns.tolist())
insert_sql=f"""INSERT INTO table2 ({cols}) SELECT {new_cols} FROM table1 WHERE id=%s""" #insert it into table2
delete_sql = """DELETE from table1 WHERE id=%s"""
select_sql = "SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE id=%s"

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    id=row['ID']
    cursor.execute(select_sql, (id,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if not row:
        print('insert') # if not, move on.

    else: #If ID in, update, move and delete
        cursor.execute(insert_sql, (False, '2022-01-10', id))
        cursor.execute(delete_sql, (id,))
        mydb.commit()
```

You should only commit once for each set of operations when moving and deleting, so that they're an atomic set.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm trying it out now. I think the first row of your code has one () to many (after columns. Should be: cols = ",".join(f"`{col}`" for col in df.columns.tolist())

Comment: And the same goes for the second row.

Comment: Shouldn't iterrows rows be used as the second argument in execute?

Comment: Why? You're copying from the table, not the dataframe. The dataframe is just being used to get the IDs.

Comment: I thought this: cursor.execute(insert_sql, (False, '2022-01-10', id)) must be like this: cursor.execute(insert_sql, tuple(row[['REMOVED', 'REMOVED_DATE' 'ID']]))

Comment: to make the iterrows work?

Comment: You said you want to copy move rows from table1 to table2. You didn't say anything about copying columns from the df to the table.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. But in order to make the code work for larger datasets, I need to use tuple(row) to get the vals for the query in execute?

Comment: You would only use `tuple(row)` in `execute()` if you need to substitute all the columns from the df into the query, and in the same order. In most cases you only need some columns, so you write `(row['col1'], row['col2'])`